# 301 Redirect New Website URL Structure .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My website is changing URLs and will remove the file extension `.html`

OLD URL:

```
http://example.com/states.html
```

NEW URL:

```
http://example.com/states
```

How can I set up my `.htaccess` file to do a site-wide redirect removing the `.html` extension?

Answer (score 1):

To redirect from `.html` to extensionless URLs, try the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file (before the front controller that is rewriting your "pretty" URLs).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. 301s are cached by the browser so can make testing problematic if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```